# Need to parse the following sed command: sed -e 's/ /\'$'\n/g'

Tags: sed

I stumble upon the command `sed -e 's/ /\'$'\n/g'`that supposedly takes an input and split all spaces into new lines. Still, I don't quite get how the `'$'` works in the command. I know that `s` stands for substitute, `/ /` stands for the blank spac, `\n` stands for new line and `/g` is for global replacement, but not sure how `\'$'` fits in the picture. Anybody who can shed some light here will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically it's meant for platform portability. With GNU sed it would be just

```
sed -e 's/ /\n/g'
```

because GNU sed is able to interpret `\n` as new line.

However, other versions of sed, like the BSD version (that comes with MacOS) do not interprete `\n` as newline.

That's why the command is build out of two parts

```
sed -e 's/ /\' part2: $'\n/g'
```

The `$'\n/g'`  is an [ANSI C](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) string parsed by the shell before executing sed. Escape sequences like `\n` will get expanded in such strings. Doing so, the author of the command passed a literal new line (`0xa`) to the sed command rather than passing the escape sequence `\n`. (`0x5c 0x6e`).

One more thing, since the newline (`0xa`) is a command separator in sed, it needs to get escaped. That's why the \ at the end of the first part.

Alternatively you could just use a multiline version:

```
sed -e 's/ /\
/g'
```

---

Btw, I would have written the command like

```
sed -e 's/ /\'$'\n''/g'
```

meaning just putting the `$'\n'` into the ANSI C string. Imo that's better to understand.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I am not familiar with C, so I guess I will probably go with `sed -e 's/ /\n/g' for now! :)

Comment: I was a bit unclear. It's not really C. It's just that the escape sequences which you can use in a `$'foo'` string are defined by the ANSI C standard. Check this: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html

Comment: `<<<'abc' sed -e 's/b/'$'x''/'` returns `axc` however `<<<'abc' sed -e 's/b/'$'\n''/'` returns `sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated `s' command`.

Comment: @potong Good point. It's the \ that I was missing to explain. Also just realized that.

Comment: `<<<'abc' sed -e 's/b/'$'\\n''/'` and `<<<'abc' sed -e 's/b/\'$'\n/'` both return the required result.(I would have put this in the previous comment but formatting tripped me up!)

Comment: @potong :) I changed my answer. I think it is correct now. Let me know if not. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: I think you have an explanation. I would add that `\ ` is what goes before a newline and does not unquote the single quote which follows it. This is clearer when using the `a`,`i`, and`c` commands where a single `\ ` followed by a new line allows for another line of input. Finally, a single quote cannot exist within a single quoted string i.e. `'...\'...' is an error whereas '...'\''...' is not